# Can't make URL clickable in UITextView

Tags: ios, url, interface-builder, uitextview, clickable

I'm using Interface Builder to layout my app.  I have a UITextView that contains some text, part of which is a URL that I'd like to make clickable (e.g. launches a browser).  I've read up on how to do this and believe I'm doing it correctly, however while the URL appears blue/clickable, clicking it in the iPhone emulator doesn't work.  Nothing happens.

My controller:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *review;
@end
```

In my implementation I `@synthesize review;` (and am able to manipulate the view's text, so don't think that's the issue).

In IB I have:

[image: IB Settings]

..then later when I go to set the text (and attempt to make URLs in the view clickable) I do:

```
self.review.text = content;
// My understanding is that this makes URLs clickable...
self.review.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

...which displays something like:

[image: Simulator Output]

...which really looks like it wants to work, however when clicking the URL nothing happens.  What am I missing?

**--UPDATE--**

Tried adding `self.review.editable = NO;` in response to Dixit Patel's answer, but it didn't fix the issue:

```
self.review.text = content;
// My understanding is that this makes URLs clickable...
self.review.editable = NO; 
self.review.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue was that `User Interaction Enabled` wasn't checked at the bottom of the View section of IB's Attributes Inspector.

Comment: You made my day dear!

Answer (score 65):

Check the "Selectable" and "Links" checkboxes in the textview **Attributes Inspector**:

[image]

Comment: self.selectable = true

Comment: @AntonTropashko Actually there is a button for that in the Storyboard editor. It's in Attributes Inspector.