# NSRange, Find a word within a paragraph getting wrong results

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nsrange

Ive written a method to highlight a word within a paragraph by sending it an `NSString` of that word, it was working perfectly until i faced this scenario:

When i have this text:

> Their mother has tried dressing them in other ...

When I'm passing the word `other`, the word "m`other`" is being highlighted, also when I'm passing `in` i got "dress`in`g".

**Here is my code:**

```
-(void)setTextHighlited :(NSString *)txt{
    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.textLabel.text];

    for (NSString *word in [self.textLabel.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {

        if ([word hasPrefix:txt]) {
            NSRange range=[self.textLabel.text rangeOfString:word];
            [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:range];
    }
```

I've tried to use [rangeOfString:options:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:) with all of its options, but still have the same problem.

Please advice

**PS:** [This is the source of my code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20171450/1091539)

Comment: An `NSRegularExpression` could be the solution. The range return is normal behavior of `rangeOfString`.

Comment: Any example on that \

Comment: @HashmatKhalil i need the solution using NSRange not by NSPredicate !

Comment: A bit verbose but there is some examples of using NSRegularExpression. Tut seems appropriate to what you are doing anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that

```
NSRange range=[self.textLabel.text rangeOfString:word];
```

finds the *first* occurrence of the word in the text. A better option is to
enumerate the text by words:

```
-(void)setTextHighlited :(NSString *)txt{

    NSString *text = self.textLabel.text;
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text];

    [text enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])
                             options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                                 if ([substring isEqualToString:txt]) {
                                     [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:substringRange];
                                 }
                             }];
    self.textLabel.attributedText = string;
}
```

This method has more advantages, for example it will find a word even if it is
enclosed in quotation marks or surrounded by punctuation.