# How to create a clickable textview as a part of a sentence in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uilabel, uitextview, xcode8

I'm new to iOS development. I want to create a clickable & bold text in a single sentence as described in picture below:

---

[image: Example]

---

In my picture above, every bold text should be clickable.
How can I do that in Swift 3? Is there any library that supports such features?

I found [this library on Cocoapods](https://github.com/optonaut/ActiveLabel.swift) and [this reference on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044180/what-is-the-equivalent-of-androids-spannable-in-objective-c), which one would have the same result as my requirements?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your text should open a link ? If yes, you should take a look about attribued text

Comment: @ArnaudWurmel, Not for a link, but like Instagram, Path, and other socmed did (I don't know what to call it). When I mention friends on my Instagram post then my friend's name on my post will be clickable.. Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try attributed text for my app.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39946005/2227743