# How to add a button on UITextView link attributes?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` and I want to set a button on every link which contains in the text view. I already underlined it. But didn't get a way to set a button on it. My purpose is set a white background and change the colour of the link. Also that button edges should be rounded.

I underlined it like following,

```
cell.text.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]};
```

How may I add a button or clickable item with white background, blue text color and round edges?

Comment: [do the answers in this very related question help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387024/cant-make-url-clickable-in-uitextview)?  or do you really want it to be a button?

Comment: I want it to be a button.